# Using IF statement to compare values of two columns, how to swap value in one column for other based on statement

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, multiple-columns

So I have a dateframe that looks like below. If the value in the PM_base column is larger than that in the PM_RAMP column (Row 15) I want the value in the PM_base column to revert to the PM_RAMP value.

I have used the following code however, it doesn't seem to be working and gives the ouput:

the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

```
if (combined_data$PM_base > combined_data$PM_RAMP)  {combined_data$PM_base == combined_data$PM_RAMP}
```

Help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Try `dplyr`'s `mutate`-function: `mutate(combined_data, PM_base = ifelse(PM_base > PM_RAMP, PM_RAMP, PM_base))`. And `==` is used to compare two expression, not for assignment which is `<-`.

Comment: `<-` or a single `=`, that is

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(combined_data)

combined_data[PM_base > PM_RAMP, PM_base := PM_RAMP]
```

Please try and give feedback if it works.

PS: next time, please provide some data. Best with `dput()`, so it's easier to reproduce and test.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!